# Why getting screen size from Toolkit yields different results depending if there´s a JFrame or not

Tags: java, swing, casting, jframe, toolkit

[Code without frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zw1m.png)

[Code with frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LWvj.png)

The images show the 2 different codes so I want to know why the result of the screen size in both codes varies depending on whether a JFrame was created before the call or not.

As the image shows when there's not JFrame it returns a different result than the one it returns when there's not a JFrame created yet at the moment of the call so any explanation on this phenomena would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  Post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have any issues.  You might want to elaborate on your system properties

## Without frame...

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Test {

    static double screenWidth = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
    static double screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();

    static double screenWidth2;
    static double screenHeight2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();

        System.out.println("screenWidth = " + screenWidth + " ~ " + screenWidth2);
        System.out.println("screenHeight = " + screenHeight + " ~ " + screenHeight2);
    }

    public Test() {
        screenWidth2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        screenHeight2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
    }
}
```

### Outputs...

```
screenWidth = 1792.0 ~ 1792.0
screenHeight = 1120.0 ~ 1120.0
```

## With Frame

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test2 extends JFrame {

    static double screenWidth = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
    static double screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();

    static double screenWidth2;
    static double screenHeight2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2();

        System.out.println("screenWidth = " + screenWidth + " ~ " + screenWidth2);
        System.out.println("screenHeight = " + screenHeight + " ~ " + screenHeight2);
    }

    public Test2() {
        screenWidth2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
        screenHeight2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
    }
}
```

### Outputs

```
screenWidth = 1792.0 ~ 1792.0
screenHeight = 1120.0 ~ 1120.0
```

## System Properties

- OS: macOS Catalina, 10.15.4
- Java: 11.0.1

Comment: What an odd situation but thank you so much for clarifying that shouldn't be the case. I was thinking it may be something related to Java itself I didn't know. I'll check the properties as suggested and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify your code but this gives the expected results.  Always the same size.

```
public class Test3  extends JFrame {
    static Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test3();
    }
    public Test3() {
        Dimension sc = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize(100,200);
        setVisible(true);
        sc = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        System.out.println(sc);
        System.out.println(size);
    }

}
```